# Calculating centroid latitude in ArcMap throws error 000539 in Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, error-000539

I can create a centroid latitude field in ArcMap10.1 using "Calculate Geometry..." in the attribute table, but when I try the same thing using: 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(bins_WGS84, "cent_lat", "!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y!", "PYTHON_9.3"),

I get the following error:  arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: GPVARIANTOBJECT0.CENTROID.Y.  It only happens occasionally, but kills my script and costs me lots of time/data. On the particular dataset I'm testing, it happens about 10 rows in, although the geometry looks fine and Arcmap doesn't complain when finding the centroid.

I know it is possible, because it's working for the same dataset in ArcMap, however, this action does not show up in the Results window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess there's something wrong with your geometry.

Try using `RepairGeometry_management` prior to your field calculation.

If this doesn't do the trick, a workaround is probably needed.

I would use `FeatureToPoint_management`, followed by `AddXY_management`, followed by `SpatialJoin_analysis`.

Edit: The best method might be via an UpdateCursor. Then you can use a try/except to find out just which features are causing the issue, and investigate further.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (bins_WGS84, ["cent_lat", "OID@", "SHAPE@TRUECENTROID"])
for row in cursor:
    try:
        row[0] = row[2][1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    except:
        print "Could not add Y value to", row[1]
del row
del cursor
```